# java ,sqlldr and shell script use for 10 million data

Tags: java, sql, shell

I want to upload 10 million data to oracle DB from a file which is in FTP.I am using a Java +shell script+SQLLDR combination in following way--

1. upload the 10 million data file in FTP manually.
2. run a java code
3. call a .sh from within the java code
4. the .sh removes the duplicates from the 10 million data file and creates a new file free from duplicates
5. the .sh calls SQLLDR to load the new duplicate free file data in oracle DB

Please advice me if I am following the optimum way .thanks to all :)

Comment: why do you delegate the dupe removal to a shell script?  Assuming the Java code reads the complete data anyways it could be better to fold the dupe checking into the Java code?

Comment: "Assuming the Java code reads the complete data " --No. The .sh reads the file -->removes the duplicates-->creates a new dup free file.I think .sh will be much faster than java to parse a 10 million line file.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you sort your data file to remove duplicates. In that case you can get better performance using direct path loading with SORTED INDEXES parameter.

Comment: Thanks Olaf.I agree with you.Waiting for more advice like these from you please.